# Apple AR Kit ( Augmented Reality Kit) gives failed assertion error msg

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Trying with the latest Apple AR kit. When executing the demo program or trying to create a basic project with AR template and running it on the device it gives the following error msg 
778: failed assertion `MTLTextureDescriptor has invalid pixelFormat (520).'
Xcode version -9.0 Beta version 
OS 11. 
Device used is IPAD Air 
Any help on this will be helpful to explore further on the ARKit

Note: Similar issue is been discussed in apple forums ref link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79050

Answer (score 2):

iPad 2017+ / iPad Pro is supported... not sure if Air will work with it